# Two bundles with @nrwl/esbuild:esbuild

Tags: node.js, nrwl-nx, nrwl, esbuild

I seem to be unable to configure two entry points for my `@nrwl/esbuild:esbuild` target. I need to create two bundles. Is this possible?

I need to output two `.cjs` files, since I am using threads in nodejs and it seems that node isn’t happy for the main and worker thread modules to be in the same file.

The documentation is sketchy  and I can't get the options on the ESBuild site to work in the `project.json`